# export ASP.NET application in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7

I've seen in this video:
http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/FT14
a feature in IIS7 that allows exporting already deployed applications. But I don't see this feature in my IIS7 under Windows7 :( . Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/514/export-a-package-through-iis-manager/) what you are referring to